# spring-boot dependency override : dependency upgrade best practices?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

is it safe to override spring-boot dependencies in applications?

spring-boot 2.3.0.RELEASE supports apache httpclient(4.5.12).

will it be safe to override in my application with apache client version 4.5.13? is there any other best options in upgrading spring-boot dependencies?

spring-boot dependencies project : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle

Answer (score -1):

if you are using spring-boot-dependencies to resolve dependencies then one easy way to put your newer version artifact ahead of the spring-boot-dependencies definition and make sure they are part of the parent pom if you have further child poms.

Comment: can you please elaborate with example?